# Couldn't execute test case parallel in serenity bdd

Tags: cucumber, serenity-bdd, parallel-testing

**When I try to execute test case as parallely inside serenity bdd projects with *mvn clean test* commands**

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <threadCount>3</threadCount>
                    <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                    <parallel>classesAndMethods</parallel>
                    <rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*TestSuite.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tags>${tags}</tags>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**multiple browser was getting up but most of them was do nothing and I saw the exception on console as below**

`java.lang.NullPointerException at cucumber.runtime.formatter.TestSourcesModel.isScenarioOutlineScenario(TestSourcesModel.java:50) at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PrettyFormatter.handleScenarioOutline(PrettyFormatter.java:170) at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PrettyFormatter.handleTestCaseStarted(PrettyFormatter.java:124) at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PrettyFormatter.access$100(PrettyFormatter.java:31) at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PrettyFormatter$4.receive(PrettyFormatter.java:65) at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PrettyFormatter$4.receive(PrettyFormatter.java:62) at cucumber.runner.EventBus.send(EventBus.java:28) at cucumber.api.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:55) at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:80) at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:140) at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68) at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73) at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:118) at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:56) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.pc.Scheduler$1.run(Scheduler.java:405) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

**and also this log messages were appear inside the console**

18:26:46.951 [pool-1-thread-3] DEBUG n.t.c.r.m.cucumber.CucumberParser - Found no Cucumber 4.2.0 class cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader try Cucumber 2.x.x

18:26:46.954 [pool-1-thread-2] DEBUG n.t.c.r.m.cucumber.CucumberParser - Found no Cucumber 4.2.6 class cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader try Cucumber 4.2.0

18:26:46.955 [pool-1-thread-2] DEBUG n.t.c.r.m.cucumber.CucumberParser - Found no Cucumber 4.2.0 class cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader try Cucumber 2.x.x

18:26:46.969 [pool-1-thread-2] DEBUG n.t.c.r.m.cucumber.CucumberParser - Found no Cucumber 4.2.6 class cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader try Cucumber 4.2.0

18:26:46.969 [pool-1-thread-2] DEBUG n.t.c.r.m.cucumber.CucumberParser - Found no Cucumber 4.2.0 class cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader try Cucumber 2.x.x

18:26:46.974 [pool-1-thread-3] DEBUG n.t.c.r.m.cucumber.CucumberParser - Found no Cucumber 4.2.6 class cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader try Cucumber 4.2.0

18:26:46.975 [pool-1-thread-3] DEBUG n.t.c.r.m.cucumber.CucumberParser - Found no Cucumber 4.2.0 class cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader try Cucumber 2.x.x

18:26:46.989 [pool-1-thread-3] DEBUG n.t.c.r.m.cucumber.CucumberParser - Found no Cucumber 4.2.6 class cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader try Cucumber 4.2.0

18:26:46.990 [pool-1-thread-3] DEBUG n.t.c.r.m.cucumber.CucumberParser - Found no Cucumber 4.2.0 class cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader try Cucumber 2.x.x

18:26:47.005 [pool-1-thread-3] DEBUG n.t.c.r.m.cucumber.CucumberParser - Found no Cucumber 4.2.6 class cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader try Cucumber 4.2.0

18:26:47.006 [pool-1-thread-3] DEBUG n.t.c.r.m.cucumber.CucumberParser - Found no Cucumber 4.2.0 class cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader try Cucumber 2.x.x

Comment: Same issue here